# ASCII value is greater than 127

Tags: c, char, ascii

```
#include <stdio.h> 
  
int main() { 
    char c = 125; 
  
    c = c + 10; 
  
    printf("%d", c); 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

The output of this code is `-121`.

How this output is `-121`? Can you please explain?

If I add `100` instead of `10` with `c` then output is `-31`.
Why?

Comment: `char`, without `signed` or `unsigned` can be either one. On your platform, `char` is signed, so you do signed overflow, which is undefined behaviour. Also, you should use the format string `"%hhd"`.

Comment: @ThomasJager: There is no undefined behavior. The addition in `c+ 10` is performed in the `int` type and so does not overflow; it produces 135. The assignment `c = c+ 10;` converts this to `char`. Per C 2018 6.3.1.3 3, the conversion is implementation-defined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point, didn't think it through.

Comment: Mujahidul Islam, There is no [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value > 127.  ASCII values range from 0 to 127.  A `char` can encode all 128 ASCII values and additionally other non-ASCII values.

Answer (score 5):

In C language the `char` type is an *integer* type able to represent all the characters required by the language itself. The standard does not specify whether it is a signed or unsigned type. After seeing the output, I can guess that your system uses a signed char of size 8 bits (7 value bits and one sign bit) and represent negative values in 2-complement.

So (as int) 125 + 10 = 135. 135 > 128 so the actual value is 135 - 256 = -121.

(In two complement mode, number are just wrapped over 2**SIZE_IN_BITS...)

Comment: Thanks. That's the main logic behind this, I think.

Comment: *and represent negative values in 2-complement* What makes you infer this?

Comment: @chqrlie: the fact that 2-complement is now the most common mode, and the fact that 125+10 gives -121.

Comment: It really a moot point indeed as the OP and most readers have never seen anything but a standard CPU with 8-bit bytes that happen to have signed `char` by default. On such an architecture, when storing `135` into a signed 8-bit char `c`, *either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.* (C17 6.3.1.3). Hence not much can be deduced from the actual stored value, albeit your explanation is consistent with observed behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie: I am old enough to remember architectures with 12 bits characters (even if I had no C compiler there...). But I would expect somebody using now a non 8 bits character to clearly state it because it is rather uncommon... But I may be too confident in question askers...

Answer (score 3):

How it works is that the type `char` in your compiler is a signed type which is 8 bits wide, and represents integer values using a system called two's complement.

In this system, the positive values go from 0 to 127 in binary like this:

```
00000000   0
00000001   1
00000010   2
00000011   3
     ...   .
01111111 - 127
```

Upon the next increment, the highest bit flips to 1: we get `10000000`. Then the subsequent binary values are interpreted as negative under two's complement:

```
10000000   128    -128
10000001   129    -127
10000010   130    -126
     ...
11111111   255      -1
```

The middle column, continuing to count up from 128, shows the unsigned interpretation of the 8 bit datum; it just keeps counting toward 255. That would be the behavior of the type `unsigned char`.

The right column, showing negative numbers, is the two's complement interpretation of exactly the same bit patterns. This instead covers a negative range of integers from -128 to -1.

Now what happens in C when we do `c + 10`?

Firstly, according to the rules of the C language, the `c` value of type `char` gets promoted to the type `int`, which has a much larger range. Thus the `int` value 125 is being added to the `int` value 10, resulting in the `int` value 135.

What happens next is that `c` is assigned that value, exactly as if by `c = 135`.  But `135` it not in range; `char` only goes up to `127`.  **Implementation-defined behavior** ensues. The `135` value is somehow forced to fit, by discarding bits.

C compilers for two's complement machines (i.e. virtually all compilers on the planet) truncate wider integer value to narrower values simply by **truncation** of the bottom bits of the value to fit the smaller type.

So, the binary representation of 135 is this.

```
 10000111
```

More precisely, suppose `int` is 32 bits wide. Then the representation of the `int` value 135 is:

```
 00000000000000000000000010000111
```

This is converted to char by chopping off the top 24 bits, leaving the bottom 8:

```
 ------------------------10000111
```

So we end up with

```
 10000111
```

in the `char` type. But what is that? Referring to our original table, we can add a few more rows:

```
10000000   128    -128
10000001   129    -127
10000010   130    -126
10000011   131    -125
10000100   132    -124
10000101   133    -123 
10000110   134    -122
10000111   135    -121 <----
     ...
11111111   255      -1
```

And there is the -121.

Answer (score 0):

The char is one byte that is 8 bit. one bit is for sign and 7 bits are all of you can use.

"char" range is:
char ==>  -128 ~ 127

```
static_cast<char>(c+1)  = 126
static_cast<char>(c+2)  = 127
static_cast<char>(c+3)  = -128
```

if you use from "unsigned char", positive range is increase.

unsigned char ==> 0 ~ 255

```
static_cast<unsigned char>(c+3) = 128
```

Comment: The C standard allows `char` to be signed or unsigned.

Comment: A byte (aka ´char´ in C) is not necessarily 8 bits.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Post _was_ tagged C++ when this answer was formed.

Answer (score 0):

`char` type is represented in memory as a `byte` (most of the time 8 bits), so it can represent values from `-128` to `+127`. If you try to store a bigger value in the memory, it causes an overflow and the result is not what expected.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXXCdVuGm70) is a nice video explaning what overflow is.